# How to find match and corresponding value in Shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have below string:

**"-owner  -date 2017-10-10 -priority 20 -value xyz -outputLocation "**

I want to ignore **-priority 20** and **-outputLocation**  options while parsing this parameters in bash script.
any trick to do this using sed/awk/grep ?

note1: parameters don't have specific order.
note2: -priority can be a number between 0-100
note3: -outputLocation . dir_name changes always with each run

Comment: Why not using getopts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

Here I am replacing the contents “-priority 20 -outputLocation” with blank space.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in -priority 20 -outputLocation
do
  sed -i "s/"$i"//g" /tmp/l.txt
done
```

**Method 2**

Here I am nullifying the values.

```
awk '{$5="";$6="";$NF="";print $0}' l.txt
```

Comment: For loop seems good, but with each run values might change. e..g for next run priority might be 40 instead of 20. Also instead of -outputLocation there might be new parameter -outputDir. so how we can handle dynamic changes

Comment: @Rock: Your question says “I want to ignore **-priority 20**”. If you want to ignore “-priority” followed by any number, you should say so in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) you can easily parse the parameters:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-owner', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-date')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

From there it's literally trivial to ignore some of the parameters.

Comment: can you please add some example using this one